# Measurable set as a subset of a non-measurable set

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

is it possible to find a measurable subset $A$ of a non-measurable set $B$ such that $A$ can be assigned the measure zero or more particularly a non zero value ( in the case of the Lebesgue measure then a strictly positive value ) ? Can you give an example ?

I am also looking for an explicit example of a non-measurable set contained in a null set given a certain measure.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "value" in your first sentence?

Comment: Take a measurable set $A$ of arbitrary measure. Take a non-measurable set $C$ of $A^c$, and consider $B= A\cup C$

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what you are hoping for by "explicit" non-measurable set. The construction (?) of such a set requires the use of the Axiom of choice. I realize that that sentence is paradoxical, but so be it.

Regardless, given a non-measurable set $C$ disjoint from $A$, then $B= A\cup C$ should work. Try showing that this $B$ is, in fact, non-measurable given that $C$ is.

The existence of nonmeasurable sets is standard in any Real analysis book. For example, let $C$ be a set of coset representatives of the quotient $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$. One can show this is not measurable. (Try it!)

Comment: It bears mentioning, regarding the 2nd request, that having non-measurable sets contained in null sets is the definition of having a measure not being [complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_measure). An example is enclosed in the link, but it wouldn't hurt to mention it in the answer.

Comment: I was talking about non-measurable sets in a general setting without referring to the real numbers, the Borel sigma algebra and the corresponding measures in which of course the AC is needed to prove the existance of non-measurable sets. Thanks for your comment.